# REGEX-JAVASCRIPT Unable to find pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to figure how I can search for a pattern that gives me only digits or digits followed by only one letter. I know I can use `/\D\g` to find only digits but I dont know how to find digits with only one letter after it. The letters can only be the following:`['a','A','b','B','c','C','d','D','n','N','e','E','s','S','w','W']`

```
  const testPattern = /[A-Za-z][0-9]/
  console.log('item_10a_object10a'.pattern(testPattern))
```

Comment: `\D` (with a capital `D` will match a character NOT being a digit!

Comment: For a start, your pattern should obviously start with a digit, like `[0-9]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to group the whole thing with `()`, and end with `/g` so it matches multiple groups.

If you want digits first then a number, you need to put the letter block after the numbers: `([0-9][A-Za-z])`

If you want multiple digits to match, you need a `+` after the numbers block: `[0-9]+`

All together: `/([0-9]+[A-Za-z])/g`

For reference, `\d` does the same thing as `[0-9]`, so you could do `/(\d+[A-Za-z])/g` instead

LPT: use [regex101](https://regex101.com/) to build and test regex queries

Comment: Thank you. That did it. I have written it down in my notes. I appreciate the knowledge. I learned something new today